Running a stream from a Python script (PyLiveStream?)
My task
The program dynamically generates videos in chunks of several minutes and puts everything in a folder (generated/0.mp4, generated/1.mp4, etc.). I need to stream them on YouTube consecutively, without any gaps between files.

The question itself
How can I alternately and continuously write frames to the stream, replacing the original video files on the fly - i.e., after sending the 0.mp4, start sending 1.mp4 without any delay?

My attempts
Initially, I found a solution using the vidgears module:
# Minimal example

from vidgear.gears import CamGear, WriteGear

output_params = {
    "-acodec": "aac",
    "-ar": 44100,
    "-b:a": 712000,
    "-vcodec": "libx264",
    "-preset": "medium",
    "-b:v": "4500k",
    "-bufsize": "512k",
    "-pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
    "-f": "flv"
}

current_chunk_num = 0

writer = WriteGear(
    output  = f"rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/{MY_YT_TOKEN}",
    logging = True,
    **output_params
)

stream = CamGear(
    source = "generated/0.mp4",
    logging = True
).start()

try:

    while True:

        frame = stream.read()

        if frame is None:
            current_chunk_num += 1
            stream.stop()
            stream = CamGear(
                source = f"generated/{current_chunk_num}.mp4",
                logging = True
            ).start()
        
        writer.write(frame)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stream.stop()
    writer.close()

...however, when trying to redefine stream, incomprehensible things happen like
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001c278113040] moov atom not found

with the further script termination.


I found the PyLiveStream module, but as far as I understood from the page on PyPI, it is a console utility unsuitable for use from my own program.


Can I (how?) adapt vidgears to this kind of task, or should other libraries be used to implement it?
